# Как найти экстремумы в списке данных?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, обработка-данных

Есть ряд данных. После смены знака числа до следующей смены знака, нужно найти минимум и максимум ряда значений.

Вот пример данных:

```
 8
-1
-41
-71
-97
-124
-126
-117
-107
-78
-26
10
46
63
94
100
88
87
105
109
81
39
7
-12
```

После первой смены знака, значения стали отрицательными и их минимум стал -126. А после смены отрицательных значений на положительные, их максимум стал 109.

```
-126
109
```

Нужна формула, как из такого списка вычленять таки значения минимумов-максимумов.

Также нужна формула, как определить кол-во положительных и отрицательных значений в ряд. Например с начало было 1 положительное, затем 10 отрицательных, после 11 положительных и 1 отрицательное.

```
1
10
11
1
```

**Обновление**

Выдает ошибку failed.

```css
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fn = r'C:/Users/Timm/Desktop/0.txt'
s = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, squeeze=True)

grp = s.groupby((np.sign(s).diff().fillna(0).ne(0)).cumsum())

extremums = grp.apply(lambda x: x.abs().max() * np.sign(x[x.abs().idxmax()]))
sizes = grp.count()
```

Ошибка:

```css
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-4d2a675b0170> in <module>()
      3 
      4 fn = r'C:/Users/Тimm/Desktop/0.txt'
----> 5 s = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, squeeze=True)
      6 
      7 grp = s.groupby((np.sign(s).diff().fillna(0).ne(0)).cumsum())

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    644                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    645 
--> 646         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    647 
    648     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    387 
    388     # Create the parser.
--> 389     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    390 
    391     if (nrows is not None) and (chunksize is not None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    728             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    729 
--> 730         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    731 
    732     def close(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
    921     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
    922         if engine == 'c':
--> 923             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
    924         else:
    925             if engine == 'python':

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1388         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1389 
-> 1390         self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1391 
   1392         # XXX

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:4184)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\parser.c:8471)()

OSError: Initializing from file failed
```

Comment: Вы можете уточнить задачу? Вы ищете локальные экстремумы? Но тогда `100` - тоже является таковым...

Comment: Приведу еще пример. Есть значения 1,2,1,-4,-7,-2,-5,4,3,1,2,-1,-2,-3. В этих значения мне нужно найти (1,2,1),(-4,-7,-2,-5),(4,3,1,2),(-1,-2,-3). Итого минимумы и максимумы каждого периода будут: 2, -7, 4, -3.

Comment: а если знак не меняется? например: `[1,2,3,4,5,3,2,1,3,5,10,5,3]` - первая `5` - также является локальным экстремумом - ее вы не хотите учитывать?

Comment: Нет, не хочу) Здесь интересует только значение 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** чтение данных из файла, подсчет числа элементов в группах, нахождение экстремумов для каждой группы (группировка по знаку)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io

fn = r'C:\Temp\.data\0.txt'
#s = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, squeeze=True)

with open(fn, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read()

s = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), header=None, squeeze=True)

grp = s.groupby((np.sign(s).diff().fillna(0).ne(0)).cumsum())

extremums = grp.apply(lambda x: x.abs().max() * np.sign(x[x.abs().idxmax()]))
sizes = grp.count()
```

или в виде DataFrame:

```
In [103]: grp.agg([lambda x: x.abs().max() * np.sign(x[x.abs().idxmax()]), 'count']) \
             .rename(columns={'<lambda>':'extremum'})
Out[103]:
    extremum  count
0
0         46      2
1       -316     29
2        148     31
3       -126     10
4        109     12
5       -168     33
6         41      5
7       -333     45
8         85     18
9       -123     17
10        70     14
11       -11      1
12        35     14
13       -97     18
14       190     75
15       -73     13
```

---

**Предыдущий ответ**

Решение с использованием Pandas и NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1,2,1,-4,-7,-2,-5,4,3,1,2,-1,-2,-3])

extremums = s.groupby((np.sign(s).diff().fillna(0).ne(0)).cumsum()) \
             .apply(lambda x: x.abs().max() * np.sign(x[x.abs().idxmax()]))
```

Результат:

```
In [74]: print(extremums)
0    2
1   -7
2    4
3   -3
dtype: int64

In [75]: print(extremums.values)
[ 2 -7  4 -3]
```

Answer (score -1):

Здравствуйте.
Вот две функции для поиска минимума и поиска максимума:

```
a = [8, -1, -41, -71, -97, -124, -126, -117, -107, -78, -26, 10, 46, 63, 94, 100, 88, 87, 105, 109, 81, 39, 7, -12]


def search_min(a):
    el_min = a[0]
    for elm in a[1:]:
        if elm < el_min:
            el_min = elm
    print("The minimum value in the list is: " + str(el_min))


def search_max(a):
    el_max = a[0]
    for elm in a[1:]:
        if elm > el_max:
            el_max = elm
    print("The maximum value in the list is: " + str(el_max))

search_min(a)
search_max(a)
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, вам нужно сделать сортировку? или как тогда вы подразумевается, что у списка будет несколько минимумов и максимумов? Или имеется ввиду несколько список и для каждого нужно найти мин и макс?

Comment: по факту это один список и у него будет один мин и макс, верно? Что Вы хотите в нем еще найти?

Comment: простите, не понимаю задачу. Может кто другой сможем понять и помочь.

Comment: лучше: `smallest = min(a); largest = max(a)` использовать.

Comment: @jfs если это учебное задание, то лучше показать алгоритм.

Comment: @OzeranskiyS. [Цели сайта другие](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286777/4279)