# Построить графики из файла txt

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, визуализация

Есть два txt файла. Нужно открыть их и построить графики. Для первого случая нужно построить график для чисел положительных и отрицательных - по отдельности. Для второго файла - график... в нем и так все числа положительные). Ну и сохранить графики)

```
55
-316
148
-126
109
-168
41
-333
85
-123
70
-11
35
-97
190
-104
42
-136
144
-22
194
-64
23
-669
```

и

```
5
29
31
10
12
33
5
45
18
17
14
```

Comment: какой график - линейный, "столбики", "пирог", что-то еще?

Comment: пусть будет линейный)

Comment: `для чисел положительных и отрицательных - по отдельности` - это две линии на графике или два графика?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

# здесь читаем данные в DataFrame:
# пример: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/630264/211923

ax = df[df['col'] > 0].plot(figsize=(14,10))
df[df['col'] < 0].plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
ax.get_figure().savefig('c:/temp/picture.png')
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

столбчатый график (используем seaborn модуль):

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.barplot(data=df.assign(sign=np.where(df.col >= 0, 'positive', 'negative')), x=df.index, y='col', hue='sign')
ax.get_figure().savefig('c:/temp/pic2.png')
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все работает, кроме сохранения графиков. Сохраняет в белый чистый файл, хотя графики выводятся

Comment: И кстати, а постройка столбчатой гистограммы вместо линейного графика - сильно сложнее? или одна строчка меняется?

Comment: @JonS., кстати, а что эти цифры обозначают? Зная больше деталей можно более дельные советы давать (иногда)...

Comment: Датчик замеряет уровень давления в цистерне при хим реакции :)

Comment: а где же временная шкала? или там интервал замеров постоянный?

Comment: Это среднее, я уже урезал лишнее