# Динамический график на Python на обновляемых данных из txt файла

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, график

Только недавно начал осваивать Python: есть txt файл, в котором происходит обновление данных в вертикальном виде:

```
0 
1
2
3
2
3
2
1
0
-1
-2
-1
```

т.е. каждое следующее значение изменяется на единицу в плюс или минус.

Нужно что бы эти значения были по оси У, а по оси Х можно просто номер по порядку (по возрастанию, 1,2,3 и тд)

Этот график нужно наложить на график линейной функции вида y=0.5x

Такой график можно сделать самообновляемым на основе изменяемых значений в txt файле?

Нашел вот этот [похожий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630334/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-txt), но не понял, как читать данные из файла txt.

Comment: Разбейте вашу задачу на отдельные этапы: чтение данных из файла, построение графика, проверка данных на изменение, обновление графика. По каждому этапу, если возникают трудности, лучше задать отдельный вопрос. И еще, обмен данными через текстовый файл не лучшее решение. Лучше забирать обновленные данные напрямую у того процесса, который их предоставляет.

Comment: для совместной интерактивной работы над общими данными, [можно jupyter lab попробовать](https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyterlab-you-should-try-this-data-science-ui-for-jupyter-right-now-a799f8914bb3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')


In [137]: filename = r'C:\Temp\data.txt'

In [138]: df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=['y'])

In [139]: df
Out[139]:
    y
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   2
5   3
6   2
7   1
8   0
9  -1
10 -2
11 -1

In [140]: df.plot()
Out[140]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x20969e08ef0>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS по поводу "самообновляемости" - стоит задать отдельный вопрос

Comment: читатели, привлечённые заголовком сюда могут выиграть от примера, автоматического обновления графика (по любому кажущемуся вам разумным механизму)

Answer (score 0):

To make gif anumation you can use:
import matplotlib.animation as animation
View video at youtube: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmYPzESC5YY

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]