# Динамический самообновляемый график на Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, график

Добрый день!

В продолжении вопроса [Динамический график на Python на обновляемых данных из txt файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788160/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-txt-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Как можно нарисовать динамический график по обновляемым данным из текстового файла ?
Данные в текстовый файл добавляются вертикально, с разной периодичностью

Пример данных:

```
0 
1
2
3
2
3
2
1
0
-1
-2
-1
```

значение изменяется на единицу в плюс или минус.

Comment: http://malev.ru/манипуляция-и-обработка-данных-в-python-data-wrangling-and/

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы в живую показывать шаги вверх/вниз генерируемые в `data_gen()`, можно использовать `matplotlib.animation`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
from collections import deque

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # $ pip install matplotlib
import matplotlib.animation as animation

npoints = 30
x = deque([0], maxlen=npoints)
y = deque([0], maxlen=npoints)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
[line] = ax.step(x, y)


def update(dy):
    x.append(x[-1] + 1)  # update data
    y.append(y[-1] + dy)

    line.set_xdata(x)  # update plot data
    line.set_ydata(y)

    ax.relim()  # update axes limits
    ax.autoscale_view(True, True, True)
    return line, ax


def data_gen():
    while True:
        yield 1 if random.random() < 0.5 else -1


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen)
plt.show()
```

С равной вероятностью шаги вверх или вниз выбираются:

[image: steps animation]

gif можно создать, сгенерировав фиксированное число входных точек (±1 шагов):

```
import numpy as np

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update,
                              frames=np.random.randint(-1, 2, size=3*npoints),
                              interval=200)
ani.save('step.gif', dpi=120, writer='imagemagick')
```

`data_gen()` может читать данные из файла в цикле и по строчке генерировать значения. Можно периодически опрашивать файл на появление новых значений или использовать watchdog модуль (или аналог), чтобы получать уведомления об изменении файла на диске. См. [Считывание с изменяющегося файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/569677/23044).

Проще возможны решения, если воспользоваться другими IPC методами. К примеру, если данные Питон-скрипту подавать на стандартном вводе:

```
import sys

def data_gen():
    yield from map(int, sys.stdin)
```

`update()` функцию нужно упростить слегка `y.append(yy)` вместо `y.append(y[-1] + dy)` (сразу значение генерируется, а не изменение).

Можно применить это решение и для случая со входным файлом, если воспользоваться внешней `tail` утилитой:

```
$ tail -F input.txt | python -m live-steps
```

Здесь `input.txt` это ваш входной файл, а `live-steps.py` скрипт живой график показывает.

Comment: JFS, Спасибо Вам большое за пример, но мои текущие знания никак не позволяют реализовать задуманное , хотя чувствую что это достаточно просто должно быть, мне непонятно как брать данные с моего текстового файла.

Comment: @indigoman: какой конкретно шаг сложности вызывает? К примеру, есть ли затруднения с запуском `tail -F input.txt` команды?

Comment: эх, у меня это все еще и на windows, tail не могу использовать к сожалению. Как работает библиотека matplotlib.animation вроде понятно. Вы пишите что в данном примере  "data_gen() может  читать данные из файла в цикле и по строчке генерировать значения" Вот это не могу реализовать. Файл текстовый, вертикально в него добавляются числа, частота добавления 1-2 раза в секунду. Вот по этим числам и надо построить график.

Comment: @indigoman нажмите на ссылку выше "считывание с изменяющегося файла" или задайте вопрос как tail на Windows сделать https://stackoverflow.com/a/188126/4279