# Как анимировать график?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, график

Подскажите есть ли возможность в jupyter рисовать анимированные графики, вроде графика загрузки процессора в реальном времени? Пытаюсь сделать мониторинг времени ответа сервера на пинг.
Разбираюсь с matplotlib, но то ли он такого не умеет, то ли я не нашел:

```
import subprocess
import re
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def ping(adress):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe",adress], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    out = p.communicate()[0]
    t = re.search(r'time=(\d*)',str(out))
    time = t.group().replace('time=','') if t else '0'
    return (time)

x=[0]

%matplotlib inline

for i in range(0,10):
    x.append(ping('ya.ru'))
    plt.plot(x)
```

График просчитывается весь и отрисовывается весь сразу. Подскажите, как сделать анимацию и возможно ли вообще такое?

Comment: [связанный вопрос ...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/789210/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Можно так сделать:

```
import psutil
from datetime import datetime as dt
from collections import deque
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
import matplotlib.animation as animation

%matplotlib notebook

N=600
x = deque([date2num(dt.now())], maxlen=N)
y = deque([0], maxlen=N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,3))
line, = ax.plot_date(x, y, marker="")

ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

def get_data():
    # return ping('ya.ru')
    return psutil.cpu_percent(.15)

def animate(i):
    x.append(date2num(dt.now()))
    y.append(get_data())
    ax.relim(visible_only=True)
    ax.autoscale_view(True)
    line.set_data(x, y)
    ax.fill_between(x, -0.5, y, color='lightgrey')
    return line,


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=300)
#ani.save("d:/temp/test.gif", writer='imagemagick', fps=10)
plt.show()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не показывает анимацию в jupyter notebook¶ Если добавить `%matplotlib inline` как в коде в вопросе, то статическая картинка будет показана. Нужно добавить `%matplotlib notebook` как рекомендовано в моём ответе (это не будет работать сейчас в jupyter lab—чтобы и в jupyter  notebook и jupyter lab работало с анимацией в реальном времени может потребоваться явно вызывать `display_handler.update()` как показано [в моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/802254/23044)).

Comment: jupyter lab не использую. На основе Вашего примера все получилось, хотя качество того что получилось не очень устраивает. %matplotlib notebook работает заметно медленнее, возможно это связано с моим железом.

Comment: @Hidden, что конкретно вас не устраивает?

Comment: Не устраивает то, что похоже для разработки простенького мониторинга я выбрал не тот инструмент. По работе нужно следить за качеством связи с несколькими серверами в интернете, думал раз у меня уже есть установленная и настроенная "anaconda" использую ка я ее. Но по факту получается что на моем железе notebook с десятком активных анимированных графиков практически не шевелится.

Comment: @Hidden, для этого существуют готовые скалируемые решения - Nagios, check_mk, Cacti, etc. Зачем изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Ну как? Изобретать велосипеды это же интересно. А так то да, уже сделал все на zabbix

Answer (score 8):

> в jupyter рисовать анимированные графики, вроде графика загрузки процессора в реальном времени?

1. Рисуем фон и оси графика:

   ```
   %matplotlib inline
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   line, = ax.plot([], [], color='g')
   time_template = 'time = %s'
   time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
   ```
2. Создаём функцию, которая генерирует текущие значения (x, y):

   ```
   import time
   import psutil  # !pip install psutil

   def frames():    
       while True:        
           yield time.time(), psutil.cpu_percent(.15) # CPU % over the second
   ```
3. обновляем график и экран, используя значения полученные из `frames()`:

   ```
   import datetime as DT
   from collections import deque

   n = 1000
   yy = deque([], maxlen=n)        
   xx = deque([], maxlen=n)
   display_handle = display(None, display_id=True)

   def animate(args):
       xx.append(args[0])
       yy.append(args[1])
       line.set_data(xx, yy)
       time_text.set_text(time_template % DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(args[0]))
       ax.relim()  # update axes limits
       ax.autoscale_view(True, True, True)
       display_handle.update(fig)

   for x_y in frames():
       animate(x_y)
   ```

Если вам не нужна поддержка Jupyter Lab или достаточно конечный цикл, который как видео можно добавить, то вместо явного `display_handler.update()` и явного цикла, где вручную `animate()` вызывается, можно использовать:

```
%matplotlib notebook
from matplotlib import animation

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=frames)
```

и/или (конечное число кадров):

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML(ani.to_html5_video())
```