# как обновлять график matplotlib в tkinter раз в 5 минут данными из базы данных?

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

Что нужно: Каждые 5 секунд, считываются координаты из БД и отображаются на графике matplotlib в окне tkinter.

Что сделано: рисуются только первый набор данных и не рисуются второй набор

ВОПРОС: как исправить чтобы рисовался сначала первый набор данных , а через 5 секунд второй?

Вот обновленный минимальный рабочий код:

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Empty, Queue
import time
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg#, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class tkChartGUI(tk.Frame):       

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def get_latest_data(self, dataid):
        x_array=[]
        y_array=[]
        if (dataid == 1):
            x_array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
            y_array=[0.5,0.7,0.3,1.0,0.6,0.9,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.33,0.55,0.3,0.6] 
        if (dataid == 2):
            x_array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
            y_array=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.1,1.2,1.3] 
        return (x_array, y_array)

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Simple chart")
        self.parent.geometry("800x600+300+100")

        result_queue = Queue()
        Thread(target=self.get_latest_data, args=[result_queue], daemon=True).start()

        x_array, y_array = self.get_latest_data(1)

        f = Figure(figsize=(5, 3), dpi=150)        
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.set_xlabel("Values_X")
        a.set_ylabel("Values_Y")
        a.yaxis.grid(True, which='major')
        a.xaxis.grid(True, which='major')
        a.plot(x_array, y_array)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=self.parent)
        canvas.show()                        
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=0)

        def display_result(a, q):
            x_array = []
            y_array = []
            try:                
                x_array = q.get(block=False) # get data
                y_array = q.get(block=False)                           
                a.plot(x_array, y_array)
                canvas.draw() 
            except Empty:
                #a.clear()                            
                timeout_millis = round(100 - (5000 * time.time()) % 100)
                self.parent.after(timeout_millis, display_result, a, q)

        def get_result(q):
            x_array, y_array = self.get_latest_data(2)
            q.put(x_array) # put data in FIFO queue x coords array
            q.put(y_array) # put data in FIFO queue y coords array

        display_result(a, result_queue)

    def onExit(self):
        self.quit()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_gui = tkChartGUI(root) 
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: [Динамический самообновляемый график на Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/789210/23044)  Вы можете вызывать [функцию animate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/802254/23044) по событиям в tkinter. К примеру, по нажатию на кнопку или в цикле after(), чтобы каждую минуту: [Как сделать постоянное обновление окна Tkinter? Как избежать подвисания на время ожидания ответа от сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723165/23044)

Comment: Продолжаю исследовать вопрос...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы постоянно не считывать данные из базы данных (polling), можно
определить trigger, чтобы вызвать функцию (callback), когда в БД
интересное событие произойдёт. К примеру, когда в нужную таблицу новое
значение добавляется ([Launch a
Python Script from a sqlite3
Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33021255/4279)):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tt AFTER INSERT ON t BEGIN SELECT got_y(NEW.y); END
```

Обновления графика происходят в `got_y()` обратном вызове,
определённом в `make_callback()` ниже. Код похож на [ответ c `loop()`, определённой с помощью `.after()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/833240/23044), с той разницей,
что здесь функция вызывается, когда нужные данные готовы, вместо того
чтобы периодически непрерывно новые данные запрашивать без блокировки:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import datetime as DT
import sqlite3
import random
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk
from collections import deque

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.dates import date2num


def generate_data(db):  # generate dummy data for the example
    while True:
        time.sleep(.1)
        db.execute('insert into t values(?)', (random.randrange(100),))


def make_callback(root):
    # plot something
    # see @MaxU answer https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/801923/23044
    n = 300

    def get_t(): return date2num(DT.datetime.now())
    xx = deque([get_t()], maxlen=n)
    yy = deque([0], maxlen=n)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
    line, = ax.plot_date(xx, yy, marker='')
    format_time = '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format
    time_text = ax.text(0.5, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

    # add to GUI
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    def got_y(y):
        # update plot
        xx.append(get_t())
        yy.append(int(y))
        line.set_data(xx, yy)
        ax.fill_between(xx, 0, yy, color='lightgrey')
        time_text.set_text(format_time(DT.datetime.now()))
        ax.relim()  # update axes limits
        ax.autoscale_view(scaley=False)
        canvas.draw()
    return got_y


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    # a dummy db for the example
    db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', check_same_thread=False)
    db.execute('create table t(y)')
    db.create_function('got_y', 1, make_callback(root))
    db.execute('CREATE TRIGGER tt AFTER INSERT ON t BEGIN SELECT got_y(NEW.y); END')
    threading.Thread(target=generate_data, args=[db], daemon=True).start()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Здесь `db.create_function()` определяет какая Питон-функция используется в качестве `got_y(y)` обратного вызова. В примере, callback вызывается в дочернем потоке, что не всегда желаемо. Поток с `generate_data()` используется только для примера, фактически данные могут вставляться в базу данных из другого процесса или других машин. [How to receive automatic notifications about changes in tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21117431/4279)

---

Для сравнения вот вариант с polling, где база данных постоянно
опрашивается в фоновом потоке, используя простой цикл (про
достоинства и недостатки цикла подробно описано в [Как правильно сделать
временный цикл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577284/23044))

```
def poll_db(interval=5):
    while True:
        time.sleep(interval - time.time() % interval)  # avoid drift
        emit(get_y_from_db())
```

здесь `get_y_from_db()` делает запрос к базе данных, а `emit()`
генерирует событие для GUI:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk

def get_y_from_db():  # generate dummy data
    time.sleep(random.random())  # emulate blocking function
    return random.randrange(100)


def poll_db(emit, interval=5):
    while True:
        time.sleep(interval - time.time() % interval)  # avoid drift
        emit(get_y_from_db())


root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<<y>>', lambda e, f=make_callback(root): f(e.y))  # subscribe
threading.Thread(target=poll_db,
                 args=[lambda y: root.event_generate('<<y>>', when='tail', y=y)],
                 daemon=True).start()
root.mainloop()
```

Пример кода (где этот метод также используется): [вывод процесса показывается в Tkinter GUI с помощью `root.event_generate()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288/c6fa221a37dd8a75d4216f841cb1852f12c496d5)

---

Не на всех реализациях можно `root.event_generate()` в фоновом потоке
вызвать. В таких случаях можно использовать queue, чтобы данные между
потоками передавать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import datetime as DT
import random
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk
from collections import deque
from queue import Empty, Queue
from time import time as timer

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.dates import date2num


def get_y_from_db():  # generate dummy data
    time.sleep(random.random())  # emulate blocking function
    return random.randrange(100)


def poll_db(emit, interval=1):  # NOTE: interval is independant from the delay
    while True:
        time.sleep(interval)
        emit(get_y_from_db())


def start_polling_loop(root, q, delay):
    # plot something
    # see @MaxU answer https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/801923/23044
    n = 600

    def get_t(): return date2num(DT.datetime.now())
    xx = deque([get_t()], maxlen=n)
    yy = deque([0], maxlen=n)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
    line, = ax.plot_date(xx, yy, marker='')
    format_time = '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format
    time_text = ax.text(0.5, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

    # add to GUI
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    # update in a loop
    def loop():
        timeout_millis = round(delay - (1000 * timer()) % delay)
        root.after(timeout_millis, loop)  # avoid drift

        try:
            y = q.get(block=False)
        except Empty:
            return  # no new data

        # update plot
        xx.append(get_t())
        yy.append(y)
        line.set_data(xx, yy)
        ax.fill_between(xx, 0, yy, color='lightgrey')
        time_text.set_text(format_time(DT.datetime.now()))
        ax.relim()  # update axes limits
        ax.autoscale_view(scaley=False)
        canvas.draw()
    root.after_idle(loop)  # start


root = tk.Tk()
q = Queue()
threading.Thread(target=poll_db,
                 args=[q.put],
                 daemon=True).start()
start_polling_loop(root, q, delay=40)
root.mainloop()
```

Упрощённый вариант (с одним обновлением данных из потока), см. в [Как сделать постоянное обновление окна Tkinter? Как избежать подвисания на время ожидания ответа от сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723165/23044). Ещё пример кода (где этот метод используется): [вывод процесса показывается в Tkinter GUI, используя `widget.after()`, `q.get()`/`q.put()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288/e2e55eb6a2f4dccd8286b7bbb63d6917febf8676).

Comment: Идея замечательная! Но это следующий этап, а пока мне нужно сделать прототип при помощи кода в стартовом посте. Буду вам очень признателен если поможете с ним.

Comment: Последний пример кода в ответе (с `w.after()`, `q.get()`/`q.put()`) это явная демонстрация как рабочий код, на основе кода из вопроса может быть написан.

Answer (score 9):

Чтобы в tkinter периодически действие выполнять, можно его запускать с помощью `after` tcl команды. См. [Обновление Label из цикла в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/581331/23044).

На каждой итерации, обновляйте желаемые элементы, к примеру, как показано в [Python (jupyter) анимированный график](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/801923/23044) и вызывайте `canvas.draw()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import datetime as DT
import tkinter as tk
from collections import deque
from time import time as timer

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import psutil
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.dates import date2num


def start_loop(root, delay):
    # plot something
    # see @MaxU answer https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/801923/23044
    n = 600

    def get_t(): return date2num(DT.datetime.now())
    xx = deque([get_t()], maxlen=n)
    yy = deque([0], maxlen=n)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
    line, = ax.plot_date(xx, yy, marker='')
    format_time = '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format
    time_text = ax.text(0.5, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

    # add to GUI
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    # update in a loop
    def loop():
        timeout_millis = round(delay - (1000 * timer()) % delay)
        root.after(timeout_millis, loop)  # avoid drift

        # update plot
        # cpu sine https://stackoverflow.com/q/551494/4279
        xx.append(get_t())
        yy.append(psutil.cpu_percent())
        line.set_data(xx, yy)
        ax.fill_between(xx, 0, yy, color='lightgrey')
        time_text.set_text(format_time(DT.datetime.now()))
        ax.relim()  # update axes limits
        ax.autoscale_view(scaley=False)
        canvas.draw()
    root.after_idle(loop)  # start


def quit():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()  # https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html


root = tk.Tk()
start_loop(root, 100)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", quit)
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
root.mainloop()
```

Сутью решения является `loop()` функция здесь.

[image: cpu sine]

Comment: Мне же ещё надо из БД получать данные, а это не гарантируется.

Comment: @GarfieldCat есть вопросы по ответу? Что не ясно? В чём у вас проблема с БД? Вы на ссылки нажимали? Обратите внимание особенно на "Как избежать подвисания..."

Comment: Мне не понятно про рекурсивную функцию. Мне нужно объединить поток из "как избежать подвисания" с рекурсивной функцией, и не понятно как это работает. Какую секунду, выполняется рекурсивная функция, а выход из неё какой?

Comment: @GarfieldCat в моём ответе нет рекурсивных функций. Если это не очевидно, то сперва разберитесь с более простым примером. Нажмите на ссылку: "Обновление Label из цикла"

Comment: def loop():
        ...
        root.after(timeout_millis, loop) А что это?

Comment: @GarfieldCat: если вы думаете, что это рекурсивный вызов, то возьмите [самый простой пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581537/23044) и задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос:  «Является ли `loop = lambda: root.after(1000, loop)` рекурсивной функцией?» (думаю ответ не только вам пригодится)

Comment: @GarfieldCat: значит ли объявление конкурса, что вы уже разобрались с более простыми вопросами, связанными с ["как `root.after` цикл создаёт"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581537/23044) или "как не вешая GUI, вызвать блокирующую функцию" ([передать информацию из фонового потока в GUI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723192/23044)), предполагая синхронный БД интерфейс.

Comment: after выполняет функцию через указанное время, после того, как mainloop отрисовал интерфейс, я так понял. Фоновый поток должен просто получать данные из вне и постоянно передавать их в главный поток. Но как все это объединить для моего случае не понятно.

Comment: @GarfieldCat: ясно ли, что `after(1000,..)` возвращается *до* запуска функции, не ждёт секунду, чтобы вернуться?¶ В чём у вас проблемы с `q.get(block=False)` в GUI потоке получить новые данные (внутри `loop()`)?`q.put()` в фоновом потоке добавляет новые данные, как в [примере кода показано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723192/23044)¶ Вместо `q.put()` и get() busy loop, можно свои события генерировать (`event_generate()`) и подписаться (`bind`), где хочется на них. [Пример (в отличии от q.put/get варианта, это может быть не cross-platform)](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288)

Comment: В который раз поменял код в вопросе. проблема с отображением в графике, помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: @GarfieldCat: если вас интересует "как сделать", то мой ответ уже показывает решение на вопрос в заголовке. Примеры в ссылках должны помочь его понять. Цель комментариев ваше понимание улучшить, иначе я бы информацию в ответ добавлял¶ Если вас интересует как ваш код исправить, то *"Вот код:"* — это плохое описание проблемы. Хорошее описание содержит: 1- *минимальный* *полный* пример кода, который демонстрирует проблему 2- содержит *словесное* описание, что код должен делать 3- явно содержит буквальный ввод/вывод. Явное описание чем вывод от желаемого отличается. [mcve]

Comment: Добавил минимальный, самодостаточный код.

Comment: @GarfieldCat а 2,3 пункты? Код явно сломан (содержит мёртвые или бесполезные куски). На то как текст в вопросе написан, вам ответ уже дан. Не ясно, что вам не ясно в ответе¶ В комментариях вы упомянули что из БД данные, что является крайне существенной информацией, которую вы в вопросе не упомянули. Не ясно кто у вас новые данные генерирует, что за минуту меняется. Попробуйте более простую задачу сперва: раз в минуту, показать в Label  новые данные (некий агрегат) из БД. К примеру, сколько строчек новых появилось, если это имеет смысл в вашем случае—почему гадать приходится? Явно опишите.

Comment: За минуту(5 минут) появляется новая строчка в базе данных, которую надо прочитать(сделано) и отобразить на графике.

Comment: Я, похоже гдето рядом, не поможете с ошибками?