# мигает перерисовка графиков

Tags: python, многопоточность, tkinter, matplotlib, очередь

[Код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835540/212222) работает, но при перерисовке все тормозит, и мигает сама перерисовка графиков.

Что делает код?

1. два потока и две очереди
2. каждый поток отправляет запрос в базу и забирает ответ
3. записывает её в очередь
4. преобразует в раздельные координаты при помощи функции make_x_y
5. далее рисуются графики при помощи matplotlib

Вопрос: как исправить мигание которое происходит очевидно при очистке старого графика для рисования нового?

```
import random
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk
from queue import Empty, Queue
from time import time as timer
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


def get_xy_from_db(id):  # generate dummy data
    time.sleep(random.random())  # emulate blocking function
    list_x = list(range(1, 16))
    list_y = list(random.sample(range(0,100),15))
    res_lst = list_x + list_y
    return res_lst


def poll_db(id, emit):  # NOTE: interval is independant from the delay
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        emit(get_xy_from_db(id))


def poll_db_2(id, emit):  # NOTE: interval is independant from the delay
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        emit(get_xy_from_db(id))


def make_x_y(list_a):    
    done_x=list_a[:15]
    done_y=list_a[15:]    
    return done_x, done_y    

def loop():
    timeout_millis = round(delay - (1000 * timer()) % delay)
    root.after(timeout_millis, loop)
    a.clear()
    try:
        data = q.get(block=False)
        x, y = make_x_y(data)
        a.plot(x, y)
        canvas.draw()
    except Empty:
        return

def loop_second():
    timeout_millis = round(delay - (1000 * timer()) % delay)
    root.after(timeout_millis, loop)
    a1.clear()
    try:
        data = q_2.get(block=False)
        x, y = make_x_y(data)
        a1.plot(x, y)
        canvas.draw()
    except Empty:
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    q = Queue()  # первая очередь для первого графика
    q_2 = Queue()  # вторая очередь для второго

    # соответствующие потоки
    threading.Thread(target=poll_db, args=[1, q.put], daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=poll_db_2, args=[2, q_2.put], daemon=True).start()


    root.after_idle(loop)
    root.after_idle(loop_second)

    #start_polling_loop(root, q, delay=40)
    #start_polling_loop_2(root, q_2, delay=40)

    f = Figure(figsize=(8, 4), dpi=100)

    a = f.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)  # расширим сетку для второго графика
    a1 = f.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)  # добавим второй график в сетку

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: чтобы от вас снова по капле не выдавливать информацию, просто прочтите мои комментарии к вашему вопросу на эту тему. Снова не описано *что*  (не *как*) является желаемым поведением (не используйте сломанный код, чтобы желаемое поведение определить). Начните хотя бы с минимального примера кода, который можно запустить и который демонстрирует проблему. Обращения к базе данных на фиктивные значения и time.sleep замените как в моих ответах показано [mcve]

Comment: Исправил. Минимально рабочий код - просто добавь в^W вставь в редактор.

Comment: пример демонстрирует отсутствие понимания как пример работает и зачем отдельные части присутствуют.

Comment: Очень возможно, я ж учусь.

Comment: я вам уже упоминал в комментарии, что начните с более простых примеров. Не двигайтесь вперёд пока фундамент твёрдый не получите. Вот уже [пример неоднократно давал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723165/23044). Добейтесь понимания почему block=False используется в примере.

Comment: если block=True то окно tkinter вообще блокируется так как поток ждет данные и блокирует все на свете.

Comment: где вы в ссылке увидели block=True? Не нужно не разбираясь все значения пробовать. Челси вы поймёте, почему именно block=False следует использовать, тогда легко на текущий вопрос ответить.

Comment: block=False если нечего возвращать тогда он сваливается в Empty т.е. когда данные есть рисуем в try: все нормально, а когда данных нет - очищать будет "дырка"

Comment: вопросы "как избежать подвисания GUI на время ожидания ответа с сервера" и "как от моргания избавится" имеют один и тот же ответ. Подумайте, что слова "никогда никогда не используйте time.sleep() внутри цикла событий" означают. Подумайте, к чему все эти церемонии с q.get(block=False) и многочисленными .after() вызовами, только для того чтобы единственный requests.get() вызвать. А теперь подумайте, что у вас функция get_xy_from_db() делает, в каком контексте вы её вызываете и что с циклом событий GUI происходит во время её вызова¶ В сторону: если код  используете, то полезно на него ссылку дать

Comment: Основной поток останавливается и ждет выполнения функции get_xy_from_db() и в этот момент надо обновлять GUI ещё.  after позволяет не останавливать поток рисования, а уже после всей отрисовки вызвать очередной забор данных... не знаю, так наверное.