# как сделать график в реальном времени с несколькими у осями

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib, graph, realtime

Учусь программированию. И у меня вопрос: Как можно преобразовать этот код чтобы данные из txt файла он обновлял каждую секунду, и нарисовал график с несколькими y осями и сохранял график, которую я мог бы распечатать. Также,  в файл текстовый данные добавляются вертикально числа. Получается  необходимо ее читать  вертикально. Данные: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8t5iu9guzaxeznk/tabl%283%29.txt?dl=1

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np
from numpy import array


data = pd.read_csv('tabl(3).txt', sep='\s+', encoding='utf-8', skiprows=23, header=None)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        self.title("С")
        self.minsize(640, 400)
        self.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico') #from https://icon-icons.com/ru/

        self.matplotCanvas()

    def matplotCanvas(self):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5), dpi=100)
        gs = fig.add_gridspec(19, hspace=0)
        axs = gs.subplots(sharex=True, sharey=True)
     

        x = data[0]
        colors = ['', 'g', 'b', 'r', 'purple', 'g', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'c', '#FF4500', '#2F4F4F', '#FF69B4', '#556B2F', '#20B2AA', '#BDB76B', '#FFD700', '#DB7093', '#7FFF00', '#4B0082']

        for i in range(0, 20):
           axs[i].plot(x, data[i + 1], colors[i])
           axs[i].label_outer()

    

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
       
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="bottom", fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side="top", fill=BOTH, expand=True)


        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=X)
        scrollbar["command"] = canvas.get_tk_widget().xview
        canvas.get_tk_widget()["xscrollcommand"] = scrollbar.set

            
if __name__=='__main__':
    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Чтобы инициализацию упростить, нужно просто списки для `y` и цветов использовать, дальше просто циклом проходитесь параллельно: <https://pastebin.com/vtvQ4i1C>. По анимации графика вот этот вопрос посмотрите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833071/1365

Comment: Благодаря вам вопрос с упрощением инициализации исчерпан, спасибо