# Лучшее решение по визуализации графика

Tags: python, python-3.x, графика, numpy, matplotlib

Необходим совет опытных визуализаторов :)

У меня есть 3-х мерный массив со значениями температуры (время + 2D).
Мне представляется достаточно наглядной простая визуализация

```
plt.contourf(Temp[0])
```

для среза по времени.
Однако, в идеале мне хотелось бы видеть как график изменяется (как гифка), чтобы нагляднее было видно изменение.

Подскажите, есть какое-то в меру простое решение этой задачи? Если нет, то как предлагаете решить вопрос иначе?

---

**update**

Ccылка на архив с текстовыми файлами с данными:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_4TGsjlqwwoCnvQhhLwXR20UwTXm4Fuv

Код, которым я собираю их в массив Temp:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

trialnm = "18_0___12_5\mytxtres_"
files_nb = []
files_cnt = 101

n = 999
with open(trialnm + str(999) + ".txt", 'r') as file:
    lst = file.readlines()

lst = [[str(n) for n in x.split()] for x in lst]

n_x = len(lst[0])
n_y = len(lst)

Temp = np.zeros([101,n_y,n_x])
Temp[0] = lst

for i in range(1,files_cnt-1):
    with open(trialnm + str(i*1000 + 999) + ".txt", 'r') as file:
        lst = file.readlines()
    lst = [[str(n) for n in x.split()] for x in lst]
    Temp[i] = lst
```

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801923/python-jupyter-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA)

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо! Но не мог бы ты пожалуйста объяснить, как встроить в эту логику contourf? Я не очень хорошо понимаю этот момент. И логика немного другая с тем, что мне не нужно старые данные продолжать показывать, только последний шаг

Comment: Если выложите ваши данные на какой-нибудь файлообменник, то резко возрастет вероятность полноценного ответа с примером решения. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38401705/5741205):

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def get_data(directory):
    os.chdir(directory)
    trialnm = "18_0___12_5\mytxtres_"
    files_nb = []
    files_cnt = 101

    n = 999
    with open(trialnm + str(999) + ".txt", 'r') as file:
        lst = file.readlines()

    lst = [[str(n) for n in x.split()] for x in lst]

    n_x = len(lst[0])
    n_y = len(lst)

    Temp = np.zeros([101,n_y,n_x])
    Temp[0] = lst

    for i in range(1,files_cnt-1):
        with open(trialnm + str(i*1000 + 999) + ".txt", 'r') as file:
            lst = file.readlines()
        lst = [[str(n) for n in x.split()] for x in lst]
        Temp[i] = lst
    return Temp


DATA = get_data(r'C:\temp\python_vizualization')


fig,ax = plt.subplots()

def animate(i):
       ax.clear()
       ax.contourf(DATA[i, :, :])
       ax.set_title(f'Frame: [{i:03d}]') 

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,len(DATA)//2,interval=333,blit=False)
ani.save("c:/temp/test.gif", writer='imagemagick', fps=25)


plt.show()
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Красота, спасибо!